# How to maintain the same index after sorting a Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, indexing

I have the following **Pandas series** from the **dataframe 'Reducedset':**

```
Reducedset = Top15.iloc[:,10:20].mean(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Which gives me:

```
Country
United States         1.536434e+13
China                 6.348609e+12
Japan                 5.542208e+12
Germany               3.493025e+12
France                2.681725e+12
United Kingdom        2.487907e+12
Brazil                2.189794e+12
Italy                 2.120175e+12
India                 1.769297e+12
Canada                1.660647e+12
Russian Federation    1.565459e+12
Spain                 1.418078e+12
Australia             1.164043e+12
South Korea           1.106715e+12
Iran                  4.441558e+11
dtype: float64
```

I want to **update the index**, so that index of the dataframe **Reducedset** is in the **same order** as the series above.

How can I do this?

In other words, when I then look at the **entire dataframe**, the index order should be the **same as in the series above** and **not like that below:**

```
Reducedset
                    Rank  Documents  Citable documents  Citations  \
Country                                                             
China                  1     127050             126767     597237   
United States          2      96661              94747     792274   
Japan                  3      30504              30287     223024   
United Kingdom         4      20944              20357     206091   
Russian Federation     5      18534              18301      34266   
Canada                 6      17899              17620     215003   
Germany                7      17027              16831     140566   
India                  8      15005              14841     128763   
France                 9      13153              12973     130632   
South Korea           10      11983              11923     114675   
Italy                 11      10964              10794     111850   
Spain                 12       9428               9330     123336   
Iran                  13       8896               8819      57470   
Australia             14       8831               8725      90765   
Brazil                15       8668               8596      60702
```

Comment: Can you add expcted output form sample data?

Comment: @jezrael have amended the question to make clearer what I mean!

Comment: So if `Reducedset = Top15.iloc[:,10:20].mean(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False)` then need `Top15.reindex(Reducedset.index)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer:

```
Reducedset = Top15.iloc[:,10:20].mean(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

This first stage finds the **mean** of **columns 10-20** for **each row** (axis=1) and sorts them in **descending order** (ascending = False)

```
Reducedset.reindex(Reducedset.index)
```

Here, we are **resetting the index** of the dataframe **'Reducedset'** as the index of the amended dataframe above.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation